# Using language model in CMU sphnix4 1.0 beta6

Tags: java, nlp, speech-to-text, cmusphinx, language-model

I am a newbie in Java application development and I am trying to create a sample speech to text application for converting live speech. I tried to use Sphnix4-5prealpha and found it has issue with microphone (http://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/bugs/412/). So I switched back to 1.0 beta 6. I successfully ran the helloWorld and helloNgram programs. I am not sure helloNGram is the right one for me to start with, and even if this is the right one, I have very less idea how to proceed. I cannot find any way to move forward from helloNGram. Can any one please help me with the following two things:

1. From which example should I start?
2. What will be the high level steps to achieve a generic English speech to text application with good accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

> What will be the high level steps to achieve a generic English speech to text application with good accuracy.

Use latest version 5prealpha and use CMUSphinx tutorial

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4